# Lumen JWT Authentication without Eloquent and MySQL

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I'm developing an API that uses not standard database connection that is not supported by Laravel by default. Because of that I am not able to use Eloquent Models to create JWT tokens and authenticate users. I have already implemented a custom user model:

```php
use App\Repositories\Technician as TechnicianRepository;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class Technician implements Authenticatable, JWTSubject {

    public function __construct(array $data) {
        $this->repository = new TechnicianRepository;
        foreach ($this->repository->create($data) as $attribute => $value) {
            $this->{$attribute} = $value;
        }
    }

    public function getAuthIdentifierName() {
        return 'id';
    }

    public function getAuthIdentifier() {
        return $this->{$this->getAuthIdentifierName()};
    }

    public function getAuthPassword() {
        return decrypt($this->password);
    }

    public function getRememberToken() {}
    public function setRememberToken($value) {}
    public function getRememberTokenName() {}

    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }

}
```

Using this model I am able to successfully generate a JWT token in my AuthController like this:

```php
$technician = new Technician([
    'email' => $request->email,
    'phone' => $request->phone,
    'password' => encrypt($request->password)
]);

$token = app('auth')->login($technician);
```

However I have no idea how to furtherly authenticate users based on the generated JWT token that is passed with a request.

For now I have the following contents in boot method of `AuthServiceProvider`:

```php
public function boot()
{
    $this->app['auth']->viaRequest('api', function ($request) {
        return app('auth')->setRequest($request)->user();
    });
}
```

And the following logic in `Authenticate` middleware:

```php
if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->guest()) {
    return Response::fail([
        'auth' => array('Access denied - authorization is required')
    ], 401);
}

return $next($request);
```

Even if providing the right JWT token for a user, the middleware denies access.

Any help is appreciated, because I have no idea how to develop user authentication furtherly.